# Subtraction of 2 maps

Tags: c++, dictionary

hi found this solution for the sum of 2 map , now i want insteed doing a subtraction !

the post is : [Merge two maps, summing values for same keys in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20771786/merge-two-maps-summing-values-for-same-keys-in-c)

Now I have of course implemented the function sub_pair instead of sum_pair .. but one thing doesn't found :

```
 while( true ) 
      {
          if(first1 == last1) return std::copy (first2, last2 , result);
          if(first2 == last2) return std::copy (first1, last1 , result);

          if(comp(*first1, *first2 ) < 0 )
          {
            *result = *first1 ;
            ++first1;
          } 
          else if(comp(*first1, *first2 ) > 0 )
          {
            *result =  *first2 ;
            ++first2;
          }
          else
          {
            *result = func(*first1, *first2);
             ++first1;
             ++first2;
          }
         ++result ;   
      }
```

here `*result =  *first2` should be negative ... is `inputIter1 - inputIter2` ... but if i try to put `*first2 * -1` ; i got an error of conversion not allowed ! how can i do ? thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you should rewrite it as:

```
template<class Map, class Function>
Map merge_apply( const Map &m1, 
                 const Map &m2, 
                 typename Map::mapped_type identity,
                 Function func )
{
    auto it1 = m1.begin();
    auto it2 = m2.begin();

    auto comp = m1.value_comp();
    Map res;
    while( true ) {
         bool end1 = it1 == m1.end();
         bool end2 = it2 == m2.end();
         if( end1 and end2 )
             break;

         if( end2 or ( !end1 and comp( *it1, *it2 ) ) ) {
             res.emplace( it1->first, func( it1->second, identity ) );
             ++it1;
             continue;
         }
         if( end1 or comp( *it2, *it1 ) ) {
             res.emplace( it2->first, func( identity, it2->second ) );
             ++it2;
             continue;
         }
         res.emplace( it1->first, func( it1->second, it2->second ) );
         ++it1;
         ++it2;
    }
    return res;
}
```

usage is simpler:

```
auto m3 = merge_apply( m1, m2, 0, []( int a, int b ) { return a + b; } );
auto m4 = merge_apply( m1, m2, 0, []( int a, int b ) { return a - b; } );
auto m5 = merge_apply( m1, m2, 1, []( int a, int b ) { return a * b; } );
```

and you should not provide comparator as parameter but use one already in the map to make it less error prone.

[live example](https://ideone.com/SlXx87)

Comment: your structure looks interesting !! basically i use a vector<map<size,type>> as container for my sparseMatrix class ! so a general structur is what I actually need, but could you explain a bit your code ??

Comment: @MarcoGhiani updated my answer with full implementation and live example.

Comment: for the product I think is slightly different !! consider that also when both of the terms are present the result shoul be the product .. otherwise is 0 if the therms is present in the first (or second) but not in the second (or first)

Comment: Then just change identity to 0. You cannot read and comprehend the code?

Comment: yes ... I'm not well explained ! i mean that i have a vactor of map , each vector index contains a map in which the key is the index of coulmns and the value is the value at the index (i) of the vector and (j) for the map key.. I done this implementation for containing "Sparse Matrix" in which most of the value ar zero !

Comment: So for product of 2 maps .. I meant products of 2 sparse matrix (implemented in the way that I wrote above) sorry I'm not well explain !

Answer (score 1):

When you indirect through an iterator of a `std::map<T1, T2>`, you get a `std::pair<T1, T2>` containing the key and value of that map element. So when you try to write `*first2 * -1` you're trying to multiply a pair, but you just want to multiply the value. So it should be:

```
*result = std::make_pair(first2->first, first2->second * -1);
```